# What exactly is the Readable concept in Range v3?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++-concepts, range-v3

I have coded an iterators-like class and for some reason it doesn’t pass the Readable concept as defined in Range v3. I don’t know why and I am trying to see exactly how I need to
modify the syntax (and semantics) to fulfill the concept.

What are the minimum syntactic requirements for an iterator to be Readable according to Range v3? Can that be written a set of statements-that-must-compile? (see example below)

I have an iterator `It` with which I can do the basic stuff (what I would call "readable"), yet it doesn't pass the concept check:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
...
    It i; // ok
    typename It::value_type val = *i; // ok
    typename It::reference ref = *i;   // ok
    typename It::value_type val2{ref}; // ok
    static_assert( ranges::CommonReference<typename It::reference&&, typename It::value_type&>{} ); // ok
    static_assert( ranges::Readable<It>{} ); // error: static assertion failed
```

**What other constructs involving `i` I can write that it will make obvious that `It` is not Readable?** **In other words, what generic code would compile only and only-if the iterator is Range v3-Readable?**

In many places, it says "if it behaves like a pointer then is Readable", but I can not find what is wrong with my iterator. I will be able to understand what is wrong when I see what code needs to compile?

I am trying to debug why my iterator fails to fullfil the concept (and therefore is rejected by range v3 functions). Note that is `It` were `std::vector<bool>::iterator` it will all work.

---

The Readable concept code in Range v3 https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1concepts_1_1_readable.html is similar to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/Readable

(I am using version 0.5.0 [Fedora30])

```
template < class In >

concept bool Readable =
  requires {
    typename ranges::value_type_t<In>;
    typename ranges::reference_t<In>;
    typename ranges::rvalue_reference_t<In>;
  } &&
  CommonReference<ranges::reference_t<In>&&, ranges::value_type_t<In>&> &&
  CommonReference<ranges::reference_t<In>&&, ranges::rvalue_reference_t<In>&&> &&
  CommonReference<ranges::rvalue_reference_t<In>&&, const ranges::value_type_t<In>&>;
```

So it looks like the iterator must (or can deduce) `value_t<It>`, extracted from `It::value_type`, `reference_t<It>` extracted from `It::reference`.

**I don't know how `rvalue_reference_t` is deduced or what `CommonReference` means in terms of contrains to the syntax.**

Comment: Neither It nor i are referenced in the static_assert().

Comment: @TanveerBadar, corrected.

Comment: Don't know if it's help but in https://zh.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/Readable there is a second part on the Readable concept (  `ranges::CommonReference`)

Comment: @MartinMorterol, that's where I get stuck. I don't know where `lvalue_reference_t` comes from and what the `CommonReference` part means in practice.

Comment: Well I don't know \o/. Have you look https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/concepts/CommonReference and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/type_traits/common_reference? (Still looking for `lvalue_reference_t `)

Comment: Btw, I think it's `rvalue_reference_t` not `lvalue_reference_t`and the link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/reference_t

Comment: @alfC: Are you asking about the C++20 `Readable` concept or the Range v3 concept?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I am asking about Range v3 Readable. I don't have c++20 ranges in my system (Fedora 30), although ultimately I would like to use the standard version.

Comment: `rvalue_reference_t` is, more or less, an rvalue of type `decltype(*declval<It &>())`. I say more or less because there are many cases considered. range-v3 is intended to  deal with cases that were not properly considered in the standard.

Comment: You can play with this toy example: https://godbolt.org/z/yl0YAf, and see that `Readable` does the right thing. If the iterator is not `Readable` (for example, not convertible to `value_type`, using it in `std::find` gives compilation errors. If your iterator does work with standard algorithms and yet it does not model `Readable`, please post a minimal example, so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 3):

For an iterator to model `Readable` in range-v3, it needs:

- to be dereferenceable via a meaningful `operator *`
- to either have a specialization of `readable_traits` or have a public member type `value_type` or `element_type` defining the associated value type.

The simplest `Readable` user-defined type I can think of is:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

template <typename T>
class It
{
public:
  using value_type = T;

private:
  T x;

public:
  T operator *() const { return x; }
};

static_assert( ranges::Readable<It<int>>{} );
```

which compiles cleanly with range-v3 version 0.3.5 (https://godbolt.org/z/JMkODj).

In version 1 of range-v3 `Readable` is no longer a type, but a `constexpr` value convertible to `bool`, so that the correct assertion in this case would be:

```
static_assert( ranges::Readable<It<int>> );
```

`value_type` and the value returned by `operator *` need not to be the same. However, they must be in a sense inter-convertible for the algorithms to work. That's where the `CommonReference` concept comes into play. This concept basically requires that two types share a “common reference type” to which both can be converted. It essentially delegates to a `common_reference` type traits, whose behaviour is described in great detail at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/type_traits/common_reference) (note, however, that what is described there is for the stuff in the ranges TS, which may not be exactly the same as that of the range-v3 library).

In practice, the `Readable` concept can be satisfied by defining a conversion operator in the type returned by operator *. Here's a simple example that passes the test (https://godbolt.org/z/5KkNpv):

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

template <typename T>
class It
{
private:
  class Proxy
  {
  private:
    T &x;

  public:
    Proxy(T &x_) : x(x_) {}

    operator T &() const { return x; }
  };

public:
  using value_type = T;

private:
  T x;

public:
  Proxy operator *() { return {x}; }
};

static_assert( ranges::Readable<It<bool>>{} );
```

Comment: Yes, my iterator has a `value_type`, but I there are some other implicit relations between `value_type` and `decltype(*It{})` and `decltype(*iter_move???(It{}))` that I can't figure out. (Yes, my iterator dereference returns a reference-like "proxy").

Comment: Note aside: this is probably a mistake `const T & operator *() const  { return *x; }` because the constness of the iterator has nothing to do with the constness  of the pointed-to object.

Comment: @alfC I've improved the example to show it even works with stashing iterators

Comment: @alfC Do `typename It::value_type` and `decltype(*declval<It &>())` have a common type?

Comment: do you mean that they have a well defined `std::common_type<It::value_type, decltype(*declval<It&>())>`? No, however there is a special decay function (infortunately I am apparently not allowed (by std) to specialize `std::decay`) that  makes decltype(*declval<It&>()) the same a value_type. Should I specialize  `std::common_type`? As I show in my question there is a `CommonReference` concept that is fulfill by these types.

Comment: @alfC I meant a common reference, sorry. Your proxy object needs to be convertible to `value_type &` and vice versa. Otherwise it wouldn't be usable in algorithms.

Comment: Do you mean convertible to `value_type`? (it doesn't make sense that the proxy is necessarily convertible to `value_type&`, that is the point of a proxy, take for example `std::vector<bool>::iterator it;`, `*it` is convertible to `std::vector<bool>::iterator::value_type&` but not to `std::vector<bool>::iterator::value_type` and yet it is Readable in Range v3 (see my edit).